# Which sections of Igros Moshe are in which volumes?

Tags: jewish-books, moshe-feinstein, responsa

In [*Igros Moshe*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00767AA82), the classic compilation of responsa by [R' Moshe Feinstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein), each of the published volumes contains one or more collections of numbered responsa, each concerning a specific area of Jewish law (generally, one of the four [*turim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arba%27ah_Turim) of [Shulchan Aruch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch), but there is also at least one collection on [*Kodshim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodashim) and [*Tahorot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tohorot), which don't get their own section in Shulchan Aruch). So, for example, Volume 1 contains [*Orach Chayim* - Section 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=1) and [*Kodshim Vetahorot* - Section 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=339), and Volume 5 contains [*Yoreh Dey'a* - Section 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=1), [*Orach Chayim* - Section 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=291), and [*Even Ha'ezer* - Section 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=383).

This layout presents an annoyance for anyone who hasn't yet memorized which sections are in which volumes and wants to look up a particular responsum based on a reference. They have to guess which volume the referenced section is in, flip through that volume to see if it's there, and then try again if incorrect the first time.

So, as an aid to the researcher, let's make a quick-reference list of which sections are in which volumes, including, [where available](http://www.hebrewbooksqa.org/367/igros-moshe-volume-3-missing), links to the beginnings of the sections on [HebrewBooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/) (or any other online repository that has them). Then, someone following a reference could go straight to the right volume.

Comment: There is a sefer called [יד משה](http://www.nehora.com/products/Yad-Moshe-%252d-An-Index-for-Igrot-Moshe-%252dHebrew-----%D7%99%D7%93-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%252d-%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%22%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94.html) which is an index of topics found in  אגרות משה. That might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Yserbius, All I'm looking for here is a mapping from, e.g. OC 4 to Volume 6.

Comment: this is one of the most useful posts on this website. I come back to it time and time again.

Comment: @Menachem thanks for the חיזוק! It means a great deal to me. Share the link with your friends!

Answer (score 21):

### Quick-Reference List of the Section-Contents of *Igros Moshe* -  אגרות משה

All links are to the first page of the section on [HebrewBooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/).

The end of each volume has, for each of the responsa sections, a list of "references from *Shas* and *Posekim*" and a table of contents with responsa numbers, titles, and page numbers. Links to these are included below with the responsa sections they correspond to.

#### [Volume 1 - חלק א](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/916)

- [*Orach Chayim* - Section 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=1) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=429) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=447)
- [*Kodshim Vetahorot*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=339) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=443) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=453)

#### [Volume 2 - חלק ב](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/917)

- [*Yoreh Dey'a* - Section 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=517) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=543)

#### [Volume 3 - חלק ג](https://hebrewbooks.org/59509)

- [*Even Ha'ezer* - Section 1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59509&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) / [References](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59509&st=&pgnum=396&hilite=) / [Contents](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59509&st=&pgnum=412)

#### [Volume 4 - חלק ד](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/918)

- [*Choshen Mishpat* - Section 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&pgnum=1) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=355) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=374)
- [*Orach Chayim* - Section 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=173) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=364) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=378)
- [*Even Ha'ezer* - Section 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=305) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=371) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=383)

#### [Volume 5 - חלק ה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/919)

- [*Yoreh Dey'a* - Section 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=1) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=495) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=523)
- [*Orach Chayim* - Section 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=291) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=511) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=532)
- [*Even Ha'ezer* - Section 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=415) / [References](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=518) / [Contents](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=537)

#### [Volume 6 - חלק ו](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/920)

- [*Orach Chayim* - Section 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=1) / [References](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=508)<sup>*</sup> / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=540)
- [*Yoreh Deya'* - Section 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=220) / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=547)
- [*Yoreh Deya'* - Laws of Usury](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=432) / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=555)

#### [Volume 7 - חלק ז](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/921)

- [*Even Ha'ezer* - Section 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&pgnum=1) / [References](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=324)<sup>*</sup> / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=343)
- [*Choshen Mishpat* - Section 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=198) / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=353)

#### [Volume 8 - חלק ח](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/922)

- [*Orach Chayim* - Section 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=49) / [References](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=365)<sup>*</sup> / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=411)
- [*Yoreh Dey'a* - Section 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=201&hilite=) / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=420)
- [*Kodoshim*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=344&hilite=) / [Contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=429)

#### Volume 9<sup>**</sup> - חלק ט

- *Orach Chayim* - Section 6 / References<sup>*</sup> / Contents
- *Yoreh Dey'a* - Section 5 / Contents
- *Even Ha'ezer* - Section 5 / Contents
- *Choshen Mishpat* - Section 3 / Contents
- *Kodshim Vetahorot* - Section 3 / Contents
- *Igrot Hashkafah* (letters focusing on the Torah outlook on life) / Contents
- Responsa from R' Moshe's brother, R' Mordechai Feinstein / Contents

---

<sup>* For all sections in this volume, combined</sup> 
<sup>** This volume is unfortunately [not yet available](https://qa.hebrewbooks.org/147/do-you-have-igros-moshe-volume-9) on HebrewBooks.org. The section contents reported here are based on a physical copy of the volume. (And see here for an online [product description](http://www.judaicapress.com/Igros-Moshe-Vol-9.html)). If and when this volume becomes available online, anyone is invited to edit this entry to add links.</sup>

Comment: It is astounding that vols. 3 and 9 are still unavailable on HebrewBooks, according to a a check I just performed on their website

Comment: Is vol 3 available now

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114741/759 didn't investigate yet

Comment: @doubleAA Yes it is. I've added the details