# Seeking Table of Contents for Steinsalz English Edition of the Talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, maseches-sanhedrin

I would like to know which of the several volumes of the Steinsaltz English version of Talmud Masecta Sanhedrin includes pages 72-80.

I had not been able to find this information on the web. The various booksellers provide only volume numbers, such as:
https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0679452222/theamericanisraeA/

Comment: An answer that presents a complete cheat sheet to the English Steinsaltz, similar to [this effort](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57624/which-sections-of-igros-moshe-are-in-which-volumes) for *Igros Moshe*, would get a bounty from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific pages you're looking for, Sanhedrin 72-80, are in Chapters [eight](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=72&format=pdf) and [nine](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=80&format=pdf) of Sanhedrin. According to the book-flap text in Amazon's product description for [*The Talmud, The Steinsaltz Edition, Volume 18: Tractate Sanhedrin Part IV*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375501827), that volume covers chapter seven. I infer that *Volume 19 / Sanhedrin Part V* must contain chapter eight and probably also contains chapter nine, since chapter seven is 19 pages long in the Talmud, and chapters eight and nine together are only 16 pages. Therefore, I'm pretty sure that what you need is Volume 19.