# Sources needed on Torah-Study

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, commentaries

I'm looking for the following sources, I searched for it, but unfortunately can't find them on HebrewBooks (might be my mistake though)

1. **Igros Moshe, Orach Chayim 1:20 by R'Moshe Feinstein**, in which he explains that they (the people in the generation in which the Second Holy Temple was destroyed) did not make a blessing on learning Torah (Eicha Rabba) - which means they did not relate to learning Torah as a mitzvah in its own right, but only as a means to knowing what to do. They failed to see the intrinsic value in learning Torah ([see this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45417/27180)).
2. **Torat Menachem, vol. 27, p. 108-113**, in which it is explained that the issue was not so much the blessing, but what it represents, e.g. if one learns Torah as an academic [pursuit](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5168613/jewish/Why-Were-the-Temples-Destroyed.htm#Didnt).

Comment: Igrot Moshe is here: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=63

Comment: This might also be helpful in the future https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57624/which-sections-of-igros-moshe-are-in-which-volumes

Comment: Is this the right one for Torat Menachem, vol 27? https://www.hebrewbooks.org/15985

Comment: Yes it is, see for instance very last line of page 109 https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15985&st=&pgnum=144

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mbloch for pointing to the right direction.

Igros Moshe can be found [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=63)

Toras Menachem can be found [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15985&st=&pgnum=144)