# Does the Igros Moshe hold like the Gra on use of Chomesh Money?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, vilna-gaon, moshe-feinstein

Here they quote the Igros Moshe

https://dinonline.org/2021/11/18/uses-for-chomesh-money/

That while Maaser money is only for the poor Chomesh money on the other hand can also go to Mitzvas other than feeding the poor.

I could not find an Igros Moshe online. I would like to know if the Gra also holds like that. I try to hold like the Gra whenever I can.

Thank you!

Comment: This might help you find the Igros Moshe online https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57624/which-sections-of-igros-moshe-are-in-which-volumes YD 3 is [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=220)

Comment: I couldn't find the articles quote in the Hebrew Books link - its possible they brought the wrong siman. Anyways to answer my own question it seems to be supported by all opinions and dates back to the Yerushalmi - https://asktherav.com/14281-uses-of-chomesh-as-opposed-to-maaser/

Comment: @zunior It's the right link and siman - you have to look at the second siman 93 (first set is OC)

Comment: Ok I found it. However it seems the answer is what I posted above.